# Firebase Updating User Data With Custom Fields After Creating User

Tags: json, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to update the newly created User's data. The returned JSON is:

```
{ 
"user":{ 
  "uid":"test123",
  "displayName":null,
  "photoURL":null,
  "email":"test12@test.com",
  "emailVerified":false,
  "phoneNumber":null,
  "isAnonymous":false,
  "tenantId":null,
  "providerData":[ 
     { 
        "uid":"test12@test.com",
        "displayName":null,
        "photoURL":null,
        "email":"test12@test.com",
        "phoneNumber":null,
        "providerId":"password"
     }
  ],
  "apiKey":"test123",
  "appName":"[DEFAULT]",
  "authDomain":"test123.firebaseapp.com",
  "stsTokenManager":{ 
     "apiKey":"test123",
     "refreshToken":"test123",
     "accessToken":"test123",
     "expirationTime":1571238989357
  },
  "redirectEventId":null,
  "lastLoginAt":"1571235389108",
  "createdAt":"1571235389108"
},
"credential":null,
"additionalUserInfo":{ 
  "providerId":"password",
  "isNewUser":true
},
"operationType":"signIn"
}
```

This is my callout and update:

```
createUser = async (userData) => {
  return await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userData.get('userName'), userData.get('password'))
  .then((authData) => {
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + authData.user.uid + '/').set({
       fullName: userData.get('fullName'),
       pictures: userData.get('pictures'),
       phoneNumber: userData.get('phoneNumber')

    });
  })
};
```

**Is it possible to add to the User table custom fields?**

A few things are happening. It appears that userData can not be seen in the .then statement. So to solve this I attempted to pass in the userData JSON as a param. This did not work. I then broke out each value out of userData, saved it into a const and passed that value. This did not work.

I can see that userData has values in it before the .then statement. I am able to successfully create a new user with the right userName and password. This means to me either:

A - I am not passing the `userData` JSON correctly or

B - I am not allowed to pass data to firebase like I am doing

My end goal is to sign up a user and then take all of the data they input from a registration form (aka userData) and update the user table with it.

Articles I am using are:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users
https://medium.com/mindorks/firebase-realtime-database-with-react-native-5f357c6ee13b

Main class that calls the createUser function:

```
const signUp  = (dispatch) => {
    return  async (userData)=>{
        try{
            const response = await config.createUser(userData);
            console.log('sign up resonse1: ' + response); //coming back as undefined
            //todo:: figure out how to parse out the apikey out of response
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', '123mockToken');  
            dispatch({type: 'sign_up', payload: '123mockToken'}); 
            navigate('mainFlow'); 
        } catch(e){
            dispatch({type: 'add_error', payload: '' + e}); //we call dispatch anytime we want to update our state
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that the parameter `userData` holds all the data you want to use for creating the user ("all of the data they input from a registration form").

The following should work:

```
  createUser = async userData => {
    try {

      const userCredential = await firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          userData.get('userName'),
          userData.get('password')
        );

      const userId = userCredential.user.uid;

      await firebase
        .database()
        .ref('users/' + userId + '/')
        .set({
          fullName: userData.get('fullName'),
          pictures: userData.get('pictures'),
          phoneNumber: userData.get('phoneNumber')
        });

      return userId;  //As per your comment below

    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  };
```

The `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method returns a [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html?authuser=0#usercredential) which contains a [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html?authuser=0).

Comment: thank you that worked. I think the issue was I was returning from the creation of the user rather then getting the response and pulling out the user id.

Comment: actually, if I don't return the response how am I able to return the user API key to the function that calls this function? Please see update code....I can also move this to a new question if you feel this is separate or too lengthy to answer here

Comment: I understand that by "the user API key" you mean the user `uid`. See the update.

Comment: thank you, I also realized that there was an encryption block on passing the API key which is why I was having trouble passing it. this all worked out perfectly!